# ORA-12154 with local connection

Tags: oracle

I just installed oracle 19c and am trying to inlock the HR user but when I want to connect to in sqlplus I get this error `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`.
I don't know what to do please help me

this what i get

---

```
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon Oct 3 23:01:33 2022
Version 19.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when the `TWO_TASK` variable was set to a value that can not be resolved as a TNS alias. Example:

```
[oracle@o82 ~]$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Oct 4 10:04:36 2022
Version 19.16.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.16.0.0.0

SQL> exit
Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.16.0.0.0
```

Now break it:

```
[oracle@o82 ~]$ export TWO_TASK=THIS_DOES_NOT_EXIST
[oracle@o82 ~]$ tnsping THIS_DOES_NOT_EXIST

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 04-OCT-2022 10:05:15

Copyright (c) 1997, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
[oracle@o82 ~]$ sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Oct 4 10:05:17 2022
Version 19.16.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Enter user-name:
```

Check the value of `TWO_TASK` and make sure it is unset or set to a resolvable value. On Windows, instead of `TWO_TASK`, check the `LOCAL` variable

Comment: how can i check the local variable